# how to extract only classes from all tables of a webpage in python?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

req = requests.get("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harvard_University")
html_soup=soup.findAll('table', style="text-align:center; float:right; font-size:85%; margin-right:2em;")

classes=soup.findAll('tables')
```

How to extract only class names from all the tables ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `findAll()` to select all the tables. Then loop through the tables and add the classes to a set (to avoid duplicates).

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

page = requests.get("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harvard_University")
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')

tables = soup.findAll("table")
classes = set()

for t in tables:
    if t.has_attr('class'):
        classes.update(t['class'])

l = list(classes)
print(l)
```